# Star operator in matrices and new math to find inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

### Example Calculation

I realized I could make some progress on an open problem if I introduced a **new operation**: $f(*) x = f(x)$, where $f$ is a function and $x$ is a variable, then I could make progress. It seems initially just like some new notation but its not as trivial. Consider the following transformation:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right)=
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
e^{*} & 0 \\
0 & e^{*}
\end{array} \right) \cdot(
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\ln(*) &\ln(\cos(*)) \\
\ln(*) & \ln(\sin(*))
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
r \\
\theta
\end{array} \right))
$$

Note:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
e^{*} & 0 \\
0 & e^{*}
\end{array} \right) \cdot
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\ln(*) &\ln(\cos(*)) \\
\ln(*) & \ln(\sin(*))
\end{array} \right)
\neq
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
* &\cos(*) \\
* & \sin(*)
\end{array} \right)$$
As one gets the wrong answer then as it seems associative property of matrices breaks down. Why? Because if one assumes it doesn't then one gets the answer:

$ x = r + \cos \theta$ and $ y = r + \sin \theta$ whereas if one solves the bracketed matrices first one gets:

$ x = r  \cos \theta$ and $ y = r  \sin \theta$. But it seems we can multiply by inverses that takes precedence over other operations (**inverse precedence conjecture**):

Multiplying both sides by an inverse of the leftmost matrix on the R.H.S:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\ln(*) & 0 \\
0 & \ln(*)
\end{array} \right) \cdot
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right)=
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\ln(*) &\ln(\cos(*)) \\
\ln(*) & \ln(\sin(*))
\end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
r \\
\theta
\end{array} \right)
$$

Once again, multiplying with an inverse (the inverse was using a clever guess in this case):

$$
(\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \tan^{-1} e^*
\end{array} \right) \cdot(
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\exp(*)^2 & \exp(*)^2 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array} \right) \cdot
(\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\ln(*) & 0 \\
0 & \ln(*)
\end{array} \right) \cdot
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x \\
y
\end{array} \right))))=
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
r \\
\theta
\end{array} \right)
$$

### Questions

Is there any case where the inverse precedence conjecture fails? Is there a general procedure find an inverse of a matrix with $*$ operators in it?

Comment: I don't understand your 'note' please explain why these things are not equal. It seems if I multiply starting at the right and apply your rule for scalars at each step the equality is precious what I obtain.

Comment: @Eddy ... These things are not equal as if one assumes they are then one gets $x = r + \cos \theta$  and $y = r + \sin \theta$ which is not true. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why is it not true? That is the result I arrive at trying to follow the notation.

Comment: @Eddy It's not true because we have there matrices: where  $(A(BC)) \neq ((AB)C)$... In the first case $(A(BC)) $ one  reaches the conclusion:  $x = r \cos \theta$ and $ y = r \sin \theta $

Comment: If things are not associative then you need to add some more brackets to your equations and make it clear in the question.

Comment: It would also be useful to see what the 'correct' product of the matrices is.

Comment: @Eddy I'm personally not sure how one would even represent such a product in one matrix ...Edits complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a 'general case' of an mxn matrix 'multiplying' a n element column vector, that is

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc} 
f_{11}(\star) & f_{12}(\star) & \ldots & f_{1n}(\star) \\
\vdots \\
f_{m1}(\star) & f_{m2}(\star) & \ldots & f_{mn}(\star)
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{array} 
\right) 
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc} 
f_{11}(x_1) + f_{12}(x_2) +\ldots + f_{1n}(x_n) \\
\vdots \\
f_{m1}(x_1) + f_{m2}(x_2) + \ldots + f_{mn}(x_n)
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

Thus we see that this notation is equivalent to a function
$$
f
\left(\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{array} 
\right) \right) 
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc} 
f_{11}(x_1) + f_{12}(x_2) +\ldots + f_{1n}(x_n) \\
\vdots \\
f_{m1}(x_1) + f_{m2}(x_2) + \ldots + f_{mn}(x_n)
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
and we are considering functions of column vector expressable as a sum of functions of each element, the matrix notation being useful as book-keeping.

To obtain an inverse function of $f$ is not possible in general. However, if $m=n$ and the function-matrix has one non-zero element per row and collumn, so only $f_{1\sigma(1)},\ldots,f_{n\sigma(n)}$ are non zero (and invertable), where $\sigma$ is a permutation function on $1,\ldots,n$, then

$$
f
\left(\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
\vdots \\
x_n
\end{array} 
\right) \right) 
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc} 
f_{1\sigma(1)}(x_{\sigma(1)})\\
\vdots \\
f_{n\sigma(n)}(x_{\sigma(n)} )
\end{array} 
\right)
$$

$$
f^{-1} 
\left(\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
y_1\\
\vdots \\
y_n
\end{array} 
\right) \right) 
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
f_{\sigma^{-1} (1) 1 }^{-1}(y_{\sigma^{-1} (1)})\\
\vdots \\
f_{\sigma^{-1} (n) n }^{-1}(y_{\sigma^{-1} (n)})
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

One of the cases considered in the opening question corrosponds to the case $n=2$, $\sigma(i)=i$.

**Explicit example:**

Consider the case $n=m=2$ where we have a 'matrix'

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
f_{11}(\star) & f_{12}(\star) \\
f_{21}(\star) & f_{22}(\star)
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \sin(\star) \\
\cos(\star) & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
so that there is exactly one non-zero element in each row and column. The action of this matrix can be summed up in a function
$$
f
\left(\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
x_2
\end{array} 
\right) \right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
f_{11}(\star) & f_{12}(\star) \\
f_{21}(\star) & f_{22}(\star)
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
x_2
\end{array} 
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \sin(\star) \\
\cos(\star) & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
x_2
\end{array} 
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
\sin(x_2)\\
\cos(x_1)
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
To find an inverse function we write
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
y_1\\
y_2
\end{array} 
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
\sin(x_2)\\
\cos(x_1)
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
x_1\\
x_2
\end{array} 
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
\arccos(y_2)\\
\arcsin(y_1)
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
f^{-1}
\left( \left(
\begin{array}{c} 
y_1\\
y_2
\end{array} 
\right) \right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
\arccos(y_2)\\
\arcsin(y_1)
\end{array} 
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \arccos(\star)\\
\arcsin(\star) & 0
\end{array} 
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c} 
y_1\\
y_2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \sin(\star) \\
\cos(\star) & 0
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & \arccos(\star)\\
\arcsin(\star) & 0
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
The important things to note:

- the inverse of the 'matrix' contains the inverse functions
- the functions are permuted (I expect this corresponds to the matrix being 'transposed') to preserve function action

**Tackling manipulation**

Let us suppose now that we have some 'matrices' $F(\star)$ and $G(\star)$ with corresponding functions $f$ and $g$. Moreover, we have an expression
$$
y = F(\star) G(\star) x
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are column vectors. If we can find inverse functions for $f$ and $g$ then we can perform manipulations
$$
y = F(\star) G(\star) x = f(g(x))
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
f^{-1}(y) = g(x)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow
g^{-1}(f^{-1}(y)) = x
$$
If these inverse functions can be written in matrix form then 
$$
F^{-1}(\star) y = G(\star) x
$$
and
$$
G^{-1}(\star)F^{-1}(\star)y = x
$$
Hopefully this sheds some light on your 'inverse precedence conjecture'

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems you've shown the existence of an inverse rather a general procedure as to obtain it?

Comment: If you have a 'matrix' with one element per row/collumn which is an invertible function, then the above is a procedure for constructing the inverse.

Comment: My first and last eqations combined provide an inverse in matrix form

Comment: I still dont understand the answer. Could you explicitly show an example?  Rather than a sentence: "... cases considered in the ..."

Comment: Example added, better?

Comment: Also added some info on how to think about using these matricies